# Can't negate nexus sonatype regex pattern

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, nexus, sonatype, resource-cleanup

I am trying to create a **Nexus clean up policy** to prune all unused docker images in my repository except for my "flannel" docker image.

I have created `^((?!flannel).)*$` regex pattern for all strings excluding "flannel" and tested this pattern in [regextester.com](https://www.regextester.com) but unfortunately regex patterns are not working for me, eventhough it is stated [here](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/repository-management/cleanup-policies#CleanupPolicies-ExpressionSyntax) in the docs that Nexus Sonatype supports Reges Patterns.

I am using Nexus Sonatype `OSS 3.21.1-01` version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sonatype documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/repository-management/cleanup-policies#CleanupPolicies-ExpressionSyntax) says that

> The expression engine uses an [Elastic Search Regexp query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax), from [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html).

To match any string but the one containing `flannel`, you may use

```
@&~(.*flannel.*)
```

**Details**

- `@` - any string
- `&` - intersection operator
- `~(.*flannel.*)` - any text but the one containing 0+ chars other than a newline, then `flannel` and then again any 0 or more chars other than a newline.